# How to read on iOS info from tags, that are EMULATED on Android devices?

Tags: ios, nfc, core-nfc

Basically, I need the iOS app act like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1bfTJar2NY&t=1s).

Is there any examples or tutorials of doing this (without Flomio sdk)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studying the problem I end up with a flutter [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_hce_reader/).

It reads messages on Android and iOS phones from Android devices that emulate Tag Type 4 via HCE.